# itext 2.1.7 do not have method scaleToFitLineWhenOverflow for image

Tags: java, spring, itext

scaleToFitLineWhenOverflow

Indicates if the image should be scaled to fit the line when the image exceeds the available width.
How to implement this in iText2.1.7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such version as iText 2.7.1. I assume that you're talking about iText 2.1.7.

iText 2.1.7 is 5 years old. Plenty of bugs have been fixed during those years, plenty of new functionality has been added. The `scaleToFitLineWhenOverflow` is part of that new functionality. If you want to use it, please use a more recent version of iText. All versions prior to iText 5 (and all versions in the 5.2.x range) were "End Of Life" a couple of years ago. They are no longer supported. No further development will be done on those versions. Please read the [FAQ](http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq) for more background info.

Comment: Yes you are right about the version and solution. What i need is I want to use same method for iText 2.1.7 jar, because it is a business requirement. Please inform me how can i achieve the same functionality in using this jar?

Comment: Sorry for the comment. I read the FAQ and I understood about why it can not be used. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck with that version then it is relatively easy to achive your goal. That version already has lots of scaling methods:

- scaleAbsoluteWidth(float newWidth)
- scaleToFit(float fitWidth, float fitHeight)
- scalePercent(float percent)
- scalePercent(float percentX, float percentY)

So you could scale your image that it automatically fits. Just play around with some of the scaling options...

```
img.scaleAbsoluteWidth(lineWidth);
```

or scale it

```
img.scalePercent(lineWidth / img.getWidth());
```

Comment: what is this lineWidth corresponds to? How can i get it?

Comment: Is lineWidth is dynamic? I still have problems like text is overlapping on image. I tried the methods like absolute position, space after image and space before image. But the problem of text and image overlap is still present. How can I overcome it?